# Value function does not converge when applying the general value iteration adaptive dynamic programming

Tags: programming, dynamic

Recently,I am trying to control a marco traffic system with the general value iteration adaptive dynamic programming algorithm.However,the results do not reach my expectation.

Here is the pseudo code:

[image]

I constructed three simple neural network to approximate the action,model and critic function like this
[image]

action network is used to approximate the control 
model network is used to approximate the traffic system
critic network is used to approximate the value function

However, the value function do not converge when training the critic network and 
the value function is supposed to be non-increasing
[image]

So can anyone who are skilled at approximate dynamic programming  figure out the possible reason ? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site (e.g. [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) or see the sites in [this](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4511/188976) answer) in the Stack Exchange network.